# AllowFastSave not available

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, ms-office, office-interop

`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application.Options.AllowFastSave` doesn't appear to be available in my code.  I'm using the Microsoft Office 14.0 object library, and every other property that appears on this list seems to be available except `AllowFastSave`:

All properties under options: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms264392.aspx

AllowFastSave: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.options.allowfastsave.aspx

Comment: Do you mean the property doesn't exist, or it doesn't work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe **Allow Fast Saves** is no longer an option in Word 2010 (i.e. you can't set it manually in Word's options). [This article](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/word-options-fast-save-vs-background-save-are-they/8ec8c534-cbde-468e-8a15-37a81e384586) agrees.